# External table is not in the expected format (Access 2010 VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access-2010

I am creating a form that generates a table from a query and disperses data over 7 datasheets within an excel file. The issue I am having is extreme inconsistency. This error does not always appear, and when it does it's in one of the 7 exports.

My code:

```
Private Sub cmdExport_Click()

Dim xl As Object

'Step 1:  Start Excel, then open the target workbook.
    Set xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open (CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm")

'Step 2:  Make Excel visible
    xl.Visible = True
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Activate
'Step 3:  Run the target macro
    xl.Run "PreImport"
  '  xl.ActiveWorkbook.Save
'Step 4:  Close and save the workbook, then close Excel
    xl.ActiveWorkbook.Close
    xl.Quit

'Step 5:  Memory Clean up.
    Set xl = Nothing


 ' The TransferSpreadsheet command below this comment is where the errors are occuring


DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_1", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_1"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_2", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_2"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_3", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_3"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_4", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_4"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_5", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_5"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_6", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_6"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_7", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_7"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_8", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_8"

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_9", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_9"

 ' The TransferSpreadsheet command above this comment is where the errors are occuring

Dim xlapp As Excel.Application
Set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlapp.Visible = True

xlapp.Workbooks.Open CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, False

Set xlapp = Nothing


End Sub
```

The macro "PreImport" that is being ran does the following:

1. Copies/Pastes 2 columns into a new location (to show last week's data).
2. Deletes all worksheets from `WORKSHEET_NAME_1` to `WORKSHEET_NAME_9`
3. Saves file

The main code (shown above) is supposed to:

1. Run `PreImport` macro
2. Dump data into `Report.xlsm`
3. Save file

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have the right arguments:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "QUERY_NAME_2", CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "Report.xlsm", True, "WORKSHEET_NAME_2"
```

Seems like you should be using `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` instead of `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9`. But more importantly as according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Access.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet) the `Range` field should be left blank as:

> [MSDN] Range - (...)When you export to a spreadsheet, you must leave this argument blank.
> If you enter a range, the export will fail.(...)

Comment: Which portion are you seeing as a range? I dont
`